# Sprout Forms - Possible to reduce available field types in form builder

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

Is it possible to reduce the available field types that can be used in the Sprout form plugin form builder section.

It would be useful to not let my clients be able to select the Matrix or Tags fields amongst others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sprout Forms for Craft 3 only displays fields that can be used on the form.

---

Craft 2 answer:

In Sprout Forms for Craft 2, it is not possible to toggle the visibility of the fields available, it displays all fields that can be received by the form.

Sprout Forms does break out the fields listed into option groups, so with a training-based approach, you could show a client that only the `Standard Fields` are supported and that all the `Custom Fields` require a developer to get implemented properly.

Another approach could be to use a plugin like [Control Panel CSS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss) and hide the `Custom Fields` option group:

```
.sprout-field-modal .fieldtoggle [label="Custom Fields"] {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: It would be a nice feature to be able to limit the fields available to the client as most of the Custom ones are not supported by Sprout forms .. with out having to install yet another third party plugin. This would create a clearer experience for the end user.

Comment: Voting on this too! Using Sprout Forms to allow my client to build forms and I'd love to be able to disable the majority of available form field types within the plugin’s settings.

Comment: Update: This should be addressed once we add Craft 3 support and a variety of additional updates we'll be making along along with that.